# Desfire EV1 file Access Bytes

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

Can someone tell me how to calculate the access bytes of files and applications of a MIFARE DESFire 4K EV1 card?

Answer (score 1):

The access bytes (16 bit) are split into four groups of four bit:

```
15..12: read
11.. 8: write
 7.. 4: read/write
 3.. 0: modify access bytes
```

Each of these 4 bit groups contains either a key number (0 to 13), a value specifying free access (14) or a value specifying no access (15).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i still didn't understand it completly, do u have an example for me? 
It's a shame nxp doesn't reply to my Email. I requested the full Datasheet , even wanted to pay.

Comment: @TheAustrian I'm not sure what more you expect here. THis is exactly what you asked for.